# How to set IP address of tun device and set link UP through C program

Tags: c, networking, ioctl, tun

I am writing a C program for tunnelling using Linux tun device. I am creating a tun device, setting its owner, group and persistence using `ioctl()` calls. However, for doing the tunnelling, I need to set ip address to the device and set the link up. I am currently doing this using

```
# ip addr add
# ip link set
```

I want to set the address, mask and set the link as `up`. Is there any way to do it through the program without invoking `ip` command?

I tried using `ioctl()` with `SIOCSIFADDR` command, but it doesn't work for tun device, and works for `eth0`. I get the error `ioctl() - Invalid argument`.

Following is the code which works on `eth0` but not on something like `tun2`:

```
280 void setip (int fd) {
281 
282     struct ifreq ifr;
283     struct sockaddr_in addr;
284     int stat;
285     
286     memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
287     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
288     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, in.dev.device, IFNAMSIZ);     // device name: eg. tun2
289     
290     addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
291     stat = inet_pton(addr.sin_family, in.dev.ip_addr, &addr.sin_addr); // ip string
292     if (stat == 0)
293         raise_error("inet_pton() - invalid ip");
294     if (stat == -1)
295         raise_error("inet_pton() - invalid family");
296         
297     if (stat == 1);
298     else
299         raise_error("inet_pton()");
300         
301     ifr.ifr_addr = *(struct sockaddr *) &addr;
302     /* This is just to test if address conversion happened properly */
303     char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
304     char * foo;
305     foo = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr.sin_addr, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
306     if (foo == NULL)
307         raise_error("inet_ntop()");
308     else
309         printf("main = %s, addr = %s\n",in.dev.ip_addr, buff);
310         
311     if (ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFADDR, (caddr_t) &ifr) == -1)
312         raise_error("ioctl() - SIOCSIFADDR"); 
313 }
```

I searched for methods to do this for tun devices but could not find any. All the posts I got to use `ip` or `ifconfig` or something of the sort.

Is there any way to do this through the program?
Thanks

Comment: the correct way to achieve this is using IOCTL. As specified in the documentation http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html, IOCTL allows to configure any socket devices. Are you sure, this code works with eth0? How are you creating the tun0 device? 
Sorry, I could not test the code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
I tested the code for eth0 and it worked fine. (I did some modification in the function as this is part of bigger program). I had to add a `socket()` call to get the file descriptor `fd`. The `fd` in this code is tun device descriptor.

I am using pretty much the same code as given on this [Linux documentation page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) Section 3.1 to create the tun device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. In case of `eth0`, I am using a socket descriptor as the argument to `ioctl()`, in case of tun device, I am using tun device descriptor. I created a socket in case of tun device too and the `ioctl()` worked. Following is the code:

```
280 void setip (int fd) {
281 
282     struct ifreq ifr;
283     struct sockaddr_in addr;
284     int stat, s;
285 
286     memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
287     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
288     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, in.dev.device, IFNAMSIZ);
289 
290     addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
291     s = socket(addr.sin_family, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
292     stat = inet_pton(addr.sin_family, in.dev.ip_addr, &addr.sin_addr);
293     if (stat == 0)
294         raise_error("inet_pton() - invalid ip");
295     if (stat == -1)
296         raise_error("inet_pton() - invalid family");
297     
298     if (stat == 1);
299     else
300         raise_error("inet_pton()");
301     
302     ifr.ifr_addr = *(struct sockaddr *) &addr;
303     /* This is just to test if address conversion happened properly */
304     char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
305     char * foo;
306     foo = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr.sin_addr, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
307     if (foo == NULL)
308         raise_error("inet_ntop()");
309     else
310         printf("main = %s, addr = %s\n",in.dev.ip_addr, buff);
311 
312     //if (ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFADDR, (caddr_t) &ifr) == -1)
313     if (ioctl(s, SIOCSIFADDR, (caddr_t) &ifr) == -1)
314         raise_error("ioctl() - SIOCSIFADDR");
315 }
```

Thanks Giuseppe Pes for your reply :)

Comment: this program use a same method with you:http://linuxgazette.net/149/misc/melinte/udptun.c